# MATE logs off on CTRL+ALT+F1 → CTRL+ALT+F7

Tags: debian, mate-desktop

On Debian Buster, MATE crashes/logs off when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and return to MATE using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
Processes started within MATE still show up on the terminal, so the problem has to happen if I switch back to MATE. There is a short black screen with a top left cursor, before the login screen reappears again. When logging in, everything is gone.

It doesn't matter whether I do a regular logoff or the **F1/F7** switch, auth.log contains the same:

```
2019-09-12T14:30:03.542406+02:00 [redacted] polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:59 (system bus name :1.977, object path /org/mate/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale de_DE.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

Comment: What video driver are you using? If it is a proprietary one there may be an issue with modesetting. Please update your post with your kernel version, your video driver that you are currently using, and If you find any errors in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log ` related to `polkitd` or the server crashing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @emotep suggested, it actually was a problem with modesetting. After using the solution proposed here: https://github.com/mate-desktop/marco/issues/438, it worked just fine.

My multiple screens were mirrored afterwards, though. The problem was solved by reducing the output to only one screens. Then all monitors reappeared and I was able to return to my original setup.